# Fit content of textview after change text size

Tags: android

I have text view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/item_table_light_grey"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I change size of text using code

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
textView.setTextSize(adapter.getTextSize());
```

width and height of textView not changed though text size changed successfully.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a blind guess but what happens if you force the View to be redrawn with `textView.requestLayout();` or `textView.invalidate();`?

Comment: @Sam changing the textsize will also affect width() and height() of he textview..?

Comment: The width and height are set to `wrap_content`, so just like calling `setText()` will automatically change the width and height. I assume calling `setTextSize()` shouldn't require `setWidth()` and `setHeight()`.

Comment: yes, I also guessed that if 'wrap_content' is set, width and height must be changed automatically. But they're not. setHeight() and setWidth() methods are changing nothing (width and heigth of textView are not changed). So that's the question....

Comment: invalidate() and requestLayout() also has been used. But also nothing happend

Comment: @Sam Agreed, I am wrong...I have tested, when I change the text size width and height of the text also changed

Answer (score 9):

Android does NOT refresh layout of views with "wrap_content" once it has been displayed.

So if you add a child view, or modify the content dynamically, you're screwed.

To solve that, I've written a static class that recomputes the sizes and forces the update of the layout for the views with "wrap_content". The code and instructions to use are available here:

https://github.com/ea167/android-layout-wrap-content-updater

Another solution is to set fixed values to layout_width and layout_height, add gravity="center" on the TextView, and remove the wrap_content

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone might need this now and in the future, I did a trick to solve this. If your TextVew is inside a LinearLayout, eg. with `orientation="vertical"`, then put these:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to your TextView will make its height updated when the text change.
I don't know what happened inside, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this issue would be to remove the TextView programatically and then add it again.

```
linearLayout.removeView(textView)
linearLayout.addView(textView)
```

I know it sound stupid but it works.
In my case calling invalidate didn't work, only this worked.

Depending on your implementation you need to take care of view index inside its parent